# Supervisor still has not start

Tags: apache-storm, topology, apache-zookeeper

I'm new to storm and when i submitted a topology supervisor log has

```
still hasn't start
```

configuration are

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
syncLimit=5
initLimit=10
```

version of zookeeper is `3.4.5`

i'm using

`java version "1.6.0_38"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_38-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.13-b02, mixed mode, sharing)`

storm.yaml

```
 ########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration 
    storm.zookeeper.servers: - "localhost"
    storm.zookeeper.port: 2181 
    supervisor.slots.ports: 
                - 6700 
                - 6701
                - 6702
                - 6703  
    nimbus.thrift.max_buffer_size: 20480000 
     drpc.port: 3772  
    drpc.worker.threads: 64
     drpc.max_buffer_size: 1048576
```

i submitted topology by running zookeeper first then

```
1- storm/nimbus 
2- storm/supervisor
3- storm/drpc
4-storm/ui
```

here storm ui

[image]

and Result spout cannot emitted messages and bolts too 
is there anything i can share it to solve this problem ? WHO can Help ?!

Comment: are you able to run zookeeper ? how is the configuration file looks like? also which version of zk and JDK are in use?

Comment: Thanks for replying i posted what you need hope you can find solution yes, i got message that it connected but after few minutes it closed as i posted here took screenshot of what happened

Comment: are you able to run any topology ever ? did you try running the [storm-starter](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter) project ? Also could you please share how did you start the cluster? what is your storm-ui showing ? also please share the code you are using to submit the topology.

Comment: yes i ran another topology before successfully but spout not emitted data, now i tried to run zookeeper error disappeared i guess that from my laptop i tried to run it from another computer but base problem still that spout not emitted data i'll post another details hope you can help me

Comment: what is your data source ? could you please share the code you are using for spout?

Comment: i tried to submit topology of one in the github like this https://github.com/mvogiatzis/first-stories-twitter/blob/master/src/main/java/trident/FirstStoryDetection.java but it is supposed work well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91581/discussion-between-user2720864-and-user3188912).

Comment: ok, i sent you message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for late reply , The problem was me in code . i'm using trident and drpc and i didn't write drpc client code to start

Answer (score 2):

I too was having the same issue. In my case the supervisor was not starting because of the class incompatibility between the jar files in my Topology jar and those in the supervisor nodes ( in storm/lib/ folder).
Please check your log files in supervisor nodes and post them. There may be an issue with the supervisor not starting up despite it being showing up in the Storm UI.